# Javascript functions stops working on loaded html with ajax in shopify infinite scroll on collection page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, infinite-scroll

I am facing an issue after using infinite scroll. the scroll works fine but when the next page is loaded with ajax.. My all javascript related functions stops working. My code is below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function ScrollExecute() {

       if($(document).height() - 800 < ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height())) {
           scrollNode = $('#more').last();    

           scrollURL = $('#more p a').last().attr("href");
           h = $("#count").val();
         if(h>2){
         scrollURL = scrollURL.replace("page=2", "page="+h);
           //alert(scrollURL);
         }


        // alert(scrollURL);
           if(scrollNode.length > 0 && scrollNode.css('display') != 'none') {
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: scrollURL,
                   context: document.body,
                   beforeSend: function() {
                       scrollNode.clone().empty().insertAfter(scrollNode).append('<center>Loading products.....</center>');
                       scrollNode.hide();
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                       scrollNode.next().remove();
                     //$(data).find("script").each(function(i) {
                       //eval($(this).text());
                      // alert($(this).text());
                      //});

                       var filteredData = $(data).find(".product");
                       filteredData.insertBefore($("#product-list-foot"));                   

                       $("#more").show();
                       u = parseInt($("#count").val())+parseInt(1);  
                       $("#count").val(u);



                   },
                   dataType: "html"
               });

           }
       }

     }

     $(document).ready(function (e) {

       $(window).scroll(function(){
           //$.JQUERY.doTimeout( 'scroll', 200, ScrollExecute);
         ScrollExecute();


       });
       e.preventDefault();
});


</script>
```

here is the link: https://sspeyewear.com/collections/infinite-products.. 
Any guess let me know plz

On first page[image]

Ajax loaded product is look like this [image]

Comment: What does it say in the console log?

Comment: Looks like you're getting some errors in console log: http://prntscr.com/fc1sk2
The scrolling works fine, but I noticed clicking images of loaded products takes me back up to the top of the page and focuses on the first item.

Comment: Hey @woodrow, Also if you see the first page you can try to select the variant of any product, related image will display in product images..but after load did not..

Comment: fix js error's first, it will stop js functionalities, check browser console to get the errors

Comment: Hi @Mahesh Singh Chouhan, type error is fixed..But now when ajax load content it redirects me on the top of the page..